# Angularjs refreshing after action same page

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to load a function on a link click, which works perfectly. Then angularjs does its magic until it arrives on the point where it shows the user feedback. I need to refresh the page after deleting an item, but it simply won't refresh.

Here's my href:

```
<a ng-click="deleteGroup(group.id)" target="_self">
<img src="img/deleteGroupIcon.png" width="45px"/></a>
```

here's my Controller:

```
$scope.deleteGroup = function ($groupId) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: apiUrl + 'group/delete',
        data: {'groupId': $groupId},  // pass in data as strings
        //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}  
        // set the headers so angular passing info as 
        // form data (not request payload)
    })
    .success(function (data) {
        if (!data.success) {
            //$route.reload();
            alert('groep is verwijderd');
        } else {
            $scope.group = data;
            //$state.go('userDetail', {'user_id' : $userId});
        }
    });
};
```

and my html:

```
<div class="searchResults" ng-repeat="group in groups | searchForUser:searchString">
<div class="manageGroupWrapper">
    <a class="normal" href="#">
        <div class="newName h3">
            {{group.title}}
        </div>
        <div class="newProfile">
            <img ng-src="{{group.image}}" width="200px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="imageWrapper">
            <a ui-sref="add_group" class="editGroupIcon"><img src="img/editGroupIcon.png" width="50px"/></a>
            <a ng-click="deleteGroup(group.id)" target="_self"><img src="img/deleteGroupIcon.png" width="45px"/></a>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to refresh the page? Could you give us more of your HTML source? Because, if you're using `ng-repeat` you could just remove the group which you just deleted from the array which you ng-repeat over and avoid refreshing the page in that way. AngularJS will handle the databinding and remove the group from the view as well. (this is handled by ng-repeat)

Comment: Are you using Angular routing or normal web pages (is there a # symbol in your URLs)? The alert is shown? Normally you shouldn't be reloading a page in a Angular application, just update the model

Comment: What about wrapping the delete in success in a `$timeout`.

Comment: ui router, yes the alert is shown, if the page is not refreshed, the product is not deleted until i press F5

Comment: I am using ng-repeat, are there extra steps needed? because right now it does not delete the product until F5

Comment: @NickAudenaerde the product will be deleted in the backend after your HTTP POST is succesful. You can visually delete it as well by using the AngularJS way, which is having an array of products in the `$scope` and iterating over that with an ng-repeat to show it in your HTML. When a product is succesfully deleted by a HTTP POST, you remove the product from the products array in the `$scope`. AngularJS will automatically remove the ng-repeat entry for you, since this is how AngularJS databinding by ng-repeat works.

Comment: You can either remove the same element you removed in the backend from the $scope array when you receive a success or make it so that your backend returns the new array whenever you delete an element and set it in $scope.group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $scope.deleteGroup function should remove its target group from the $scope.groups so the content of the ng-repeat is automatically updated and does not display the group anymore.

```
$scope.deleteGroup = function (group) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: apiUrl + 'group/delete',
        data: {'groupId': group.$groupId},  // pass in data as strings
        //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}  
        // set the headers so angular passing info as 
        // form data (not request payload)
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.groups.splice($scope.groups.indexOf(group));
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To force refreshing the page with uiRouter you can use `$state.go(target, params, {reload: true})`.

```
$scope.deleteGroup = function (group) {
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: apiUrl + 'group/delete',
    data: {'groupId': group.groupId},  // pass in data as strings
    //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}  
    // set the headers so angular passing info as 
    // form data (not request payload)
  }).success(function(data) {
    // This will reload the current state with the same stateParams
    $state.go($state.current.name, $stateParams, {reload: true});
  });
};
```